# Count the coins including permutations of the same sequence

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

I've found a code to find number of possibilities to make change using given coins:  [How to count possible combination for coin problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243831/how-to-count-possible-combination-for-coin-problem). But how to count it, if we think about different permutations of the same sequence? I mean that, e.g. amount is 12, and "4 4 2 2" and "4 2 4 2" should be counted as 2, not 1.

Comment: Change of coins is a combination, not a permutation.

Comment: So is there algorithm to count permutations? What's the name?

Comment: Do you want to separate these [1 1 1] and [1 1 1] or just separate [1 2 3] and [1 3 2] for example?

Comment: [1 1 1] and [1 1 1] are the same, [1 2 3] and [1 3 2] are different. I forgotten mention about it, thanks :)

Comment: For each sequence ([1 1 2 3] for example) you can arrange it in (n1+n2+...+nk)! / (n1!*n2!*...*nk!) different ways where `ni` is the number of coins of this type. In the [1 1 2 3] example: n1=2,n2=1,n3=1

Comment: Yes, but how to "extract" these sequences? It is actually my main problem.

Comment: It's said inside the link. Which part isn't clear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned inside your question you can count the possible combinations as stated in  [How to count possible combination for coin problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243831/how-to-count-possible-combination-for-coin-problem). But in order to include the permutations into your answer:

1. If you distinguish the permutation of the same numbers [1 7 7] and [1 7 7] e.g. just count each sequence([1 7 7] here) as n! (n = # of elements in the sequence) [instead of 1]
2. Otherwise : multiply each sequence by n!/(m!*l!*...) where m = number of equal elements of type 1, l is number of equal elements of type 2 and so on... . For example for sequence like [a b b c c c] you should count this 6!/(2!*3!) [instead of 1]

---

So use the algorithm inside that link, that I don't repeat again, but just instead of counting each combination as 1 use the formula that I said (depending on the case you desire).

(`!` is factorial.)

Comment: I think I don't understand algorithm in that code. I have no idea from what it depends it is counting that as 1...

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/)

Comment: OK, I understood and successfully modified recursive version. But what about DP? Is it also possible to make that changes?