# find all the possible combination of coins, implementing by recursion

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

Solve the problem by recursion:

using three type coins include 1 yuan, 2 yuan and 5 yuan, plus to 10 yuan, how many combinations?

The following is my code :

```
int coinNum(int num){
   if(num>=0){
       if(num==0)
           return 1;
       else 
           return coinNum(num-5)+coinNum(num-2)+coinNum(num-1);
   }else
       return 0;
 }

int main(){
   int num=coinNum(10);
   printf("%d\n",num);//the result is 128
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

What's the error of my recursion algorithm or what's your right code ?
**question supplement** :
1. (5,2,2,1) and (2,5,2,1) should be counted as 1 **combination** . 
2. the following is my code of the enumeration algorithm .

```
void coin(){
  int i,j,k,count=0;
  for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
    for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
        for(k=0;k<=2;k++)
            if((i+2*j+5*k)==10){
                count++;
                printf("one yuan :%d，2 yuan :%d，5 yuan :%d\n",i,j,k);
            }

   printf("总方法数%d\n",count);//the result is 10
 }
```

Comment: What makes you think there is an error?

Comment: You are asking us what is the error? You should tell us what is the error.

Comment: You ask for combination, which means (2,2,5,1) or (2,5,2,1) should be counted as 1 combination right? In your code, you cannot handle that case, ,that is your logic error.

Comment: The problem has myriad solutions on the web and quite a few duplicates here.  Try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243831/how-to-count-possible-combination-for-coin-problem).

Comment: thanks ! i am so sorry that i cannot describe the question clearly because of the first asking question here . <br/>1 . I get the result of 10 by enumeration algorithm which i think is right , so i feel that the result of recursion ,128 ,is wrong .   but i cannot detect what's the error of my code <br/>2. (5,2,2,1) and (2,5,2,1) should be counted as 1 combination .@Scott Hunter@bolov @Pham Trung

Comment: thank you very much ! I am sorry for the first asking question here.@Prune

Answer (score 2):

Your code is counting the number of **permutations** that add up to 10. You want combinations. That means (5,2,2,1) and (2,5,2,1) should be counted as 1 combination.

In this case, the answer should be 10: (5,5), (5,2,2,1), (5,2,1,1,1), (5,1,..1), (2,2,2,2,2), (2,2,2,2,1,1), (2,2,2,1,1,1,1), (2,2,1,..1), (2,1,..1), and (1,..1).

Try this code:

```
int coinNum(int num, int *coins){
  if (num == 0) return 1;
  if (num < 0 || !*coins) return 0;
  return coinNum(num - *coins, coins) + coinNum(num, coins+1);
}

int main(){
  int coins[] = {5,2,1,0}; // don't forget the 0 or the program won't end

  int num=coinNum(10,coins);
  printf("%d\n",num); // the result is 10
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

The code above tries all combinations until the sum equals or exceeds the desired sum. Note that this is not the most efficient algorithm to solve this problem, but the most simple one. For better algorithms, you should probably look for it at [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I get the result of 10 by enumeration -for , but cannot solve it buy recursion . you are so cool  !  thank you very much for your answer and the recommendation  of the book .

Comment: my code is counting the numbers of permutations ----yes !  I confuse permutations with combinations .

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but why did you confirm the answer and immediately unconfirm it.. :(

Comment: thanks , I also immediately  confirm it .@cozyconemotel Jan

Answer (score -1):

Another simple algorithm, using idea to generate not decreasing sequence of coins.

```
int coinNum(int num, int min_coin) {
  if (num == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else if (num < 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    int res = coinNum(num - 5, 5);
    if (min_coin <= 1) {
      res += coinNum(num - 1, 1);
    }
    if (min_coin <= 2) {
      res += coinNum(num - 2, 2);
    }
    return res;
  }
}

int main(){
  int num = coinNum(10, 1);
  printf("%d\n", num);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes , you are right ! so cool , thank you very much ! I may need to understand the meaning of recursion deeply . Always , i fail to find recursion algorithm to solve these problem  , do you have some advice such as some books and its like?