# Number of ways such that sum of k elements equal to p

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given series of integers having relation where a number is equal to sum of previous 2 numbers and starting integer is 1

> Series ->1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55

find the number of ways such that sum of k elements equal to p.We can use an element any number of times.

> p=8
>
> k=4.

**So,number of ways would be 4.Those are,**

> 1,1,1,5
>
> 1,1,3,3
>
> 1,2,2,3
>
> 2,2,2,2

I am able to sove this question through recursion.I sense dynamic programming here but i am not getting how to do it.Can it be done in much lesser time???

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that the sequence of the numbers does not matter and will be counted once. for ex=3->(1,2)and(2,1).here number of ways would be 1 only.

Comment: The same teacher or online contest?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193565/

Comment: It's an online judge problem.I saw it a few days ago but i don't remember from where it was.

Comment: @warrior, is the input series Fibonacci series?

Comment: @vish4071 Yes the input is fibonacci series

Comment: And the input `p` can be nything? (Not always a fibonacci number)...the example is a bit mileading

Comment: @vish4071 Yes the input p can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Poster has changed the original problem since this was posted.  My algorithm still works, but maybe can be improved upon.  Original problem had n arbitrary input numbers (he has now modified it to be a Fibonacci series).  To apply my algorithm to the modified post, truncate the series by taking only elements less than p (assume there are n of them).

Here's an `n^(k/2)` algorithm.  (`n` is the number of elements in the series)

Use a table of length `p`, such that `table[i]` contains all combinations of `k/2` elements that sum to `i`.  For example, in the example data that you provided, `table[4]` contains `{1,3}` and `{2,2}`.

**EDIT:**  If the space is prohibitive, this same algorithm can be done with an ordered linked lists, where you only store the non-empty table entries.  The linked list has to be both directions: forward and backwards, which makes the final step of the algorithm cleaner.

Once this table is computed, then we get all solutions by combining every `table[j]` with every `table[p-j]`, whenever both are non-empty.

To get the table, initialize the entire thing to empty.  Then:

```
For i_1 = 0 to n-1:
    For i_2 = i_1 to n-1:
        ...
            For i_k/2 = i_k/2-1 to n-1:
                sum = series[i_1] + ... + series[i_k/2]
                    if sum <= p:
                        store {i_1, i_2, ... , i_k/2 } in table[sum]
```

This "variable number of loops" looks impossible to implement, but actually it can be done with an array of length `k/2` that keeps track of where each i_` is.

Let's go back to your data and see how our table would look:

```
table[2] = {1,1}
table[3] = {1,2}
table[4] = {1,3} and {2,2}
table[5] = {2,3}
table[6] = {1,5}
table[7] = {2,5}
table[8] = {3,5}
```

Solutions are found by combining `table[2]` with `table[6]`, `table[3]` with `table[5]`, and `table[4]` with `table[4]`.  Thus, solutions are: {1,1,1,5} {1,2,2,3}, {1,1,3,3}, {2,2,2,2}, {1,3,2,2}.

Comment: Here p can be as big as 10^9.It won't be possible to make an array of that size.

Comment: @warrior: see my edits.  My algorithm still handles sizes that big without blowing up.

Comment: As it's an online judge problem memory won't be sufficient for your algorithm

Comment: @warrior, do you agree that the memory requirements are order n^(k/2) if you use linked lists?  Are you saying this is too much?  I'm going to say right now that this will use less than any dynamic programming solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming. Let `C(p, k)` be the number of ways that sum `k` element equal to `p` and `a` be the array of elements. Then

```
 C(p, k) = C(p - a[0], k - 1) + C(p - a[1], k - 1) + .... + C(p - a[n-1], k - 1)
```

Then, you can use memorization to speed up your code.

Comment: Yes i know this.But as p can be upto 10^9 this solution doesn't seem efficient.Can we speed this up.Can we make use of the series given or maximum value of k=10.

Comment: @warrior, it is efficient because the most important thing is not how big is p. It is about how big is k. k will determine the depth of the recursive. Since k is only below 10.

Comment: @invisal could you please include the run time analysis in your post?

Comment: @TheGreatContini, it is n^k without memorization.

Comment: @invisal I forgot to mention that the sequence of the numbers does not matter and will be counted once. for ex=3->(1,2)and(2,1).here number of ways would be 1 only.Can you tell me what to change in this recursive formula to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Your problem is well-known. It is the sum set problem, a variation of knapsack problem. Check this pretty good explanation. [sum-set problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/)